# exit status 1 'Time' does not name a type

Tags: rtc

```
#include <DS3231.h>
#include <Wire.h>  // i2C Conection Library

// Init DS3231
DS3231  rtc;
// Init a Time-data structure
Time  t;
uint32_t targetTime = 0;

uint8_t hh = 0, mm = 0, ss = 0, dd = 0, bb = 0; //variable Unsignet int 0-255
int yy = 0; //variable integer
String Day = "  "; //variable string

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  t = rtc.getTime(); // gate all data time & date from RTC
  Day = rtc.getDOWStr(); //get name of day
  hh = t.hour,DEC; //pengambilan data jam
  mm = t.min,DEC; //pengambilan data menit
  ss = t.sec,DEC; //pengambilan data detik
  dd = t.date,DEC; //pengambilan data hari
  bb = t.mon,DEC; //pengambilan data bulan (dalam desimal)
  yy = t.year,DEC; //pengambilan data tahun
  //Buka Serial Monitor Arduino untuk melihat hasilnya
  Serial.print (Day);
  Serial.print (F(" Time = "));
  Serial.print (hh); Serial.print (F(" : "));
  Serial.print (mm); Serial.print (F(" : "));
  Serial.print (ss); Serial.print (F("  Date = "));
  Serial.print (dd); Serial.print (F(" . "));
  Serial.print (bb); Serial.print (F(" . "));
  Serial.println (yy);
  delay (1000);
}
```

When I verify the code, this error appears:

> exit status 1
>   'Time' does not name a type

What does it mean?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Please format your code properly using the `{}` code button (or add >= 4 spaces on the start of each line). Make sure it is indented properly. Use the preview to check it before submitting.

Comment: Have you included the library that defines the "Time" type?

Comment: isn't it already in the library wire.h?

Comment: @Hanatsuki No - see http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Time

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention which library you are using (which library does `#include <DS3231.h>` refer to?)

The DS3231 library here https://github.com/NorthernWidget/DS3231 defines a `DateTime` object which appears to have similar elements to what you are trying to access in 't' (hour, min, sec etc).

I would try defining 't' as a `DateTime` object.